# Kendo Scheduler - AllDaySlot(false) but must keep All Day tasks

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I have set the `AllDaySlot` to false, as we do not want that slot at the top. But we want to see the tasks that spans over 24 hours or more, as we see the reguluar tasks that is less than 24 hours.

Now, after the `AllDaySlot` is set to false, the tasks that have a greater timespan than 24 hours will just not appear in the scheduler.

Does Kendo havea an easy way to keep the tasks?

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce youre problem, interisting is that the event is there (my validation tells me) but you cant see it and it was not in the DOM.

Comment: Exactly - it does not remove the event, but it cant show it.

Comment: You can reproduce youre error hier in http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/scheduler/restriction.html i thing its a bug, it will maybe help if you post it on Kendo forum for bug fix. Sry that it dosent help you now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes This seems like a bug.  In my case, I have an event that spans say Feb 1st 1pm to Feb 2nd 5pm.  So it shows it as all day for both days, which really isn't the case.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make day events span multiple days by modifying the kendo scheduler source code.

For example, in `_renderEvents(events, groupIndex)` in kendo.scheduler.dayview.js dont set isMultiDayEvent to true if this event spans more than `MS_PER_DAY`

You'll also find this same sort of occurrence in `isMultiDay()` in kendo.scheduler.js